# I want to graph taylor series in python use matplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy, taylor-series

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np

x=sy.Symbol('x')

plt.title("Comparison of EXP(x), PP1, PP2")
plt.xlim(0-0.1, 3+0.2)
plt.ylim(0, 20+1)
plt.xlabel("x") 
plt.ylabel("y: values")
plt.grid(False)


x=np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.exp(x), label="exp(x)")
plt.plot(x, np.exp(x).series(x, 0, 4), label="PP1")
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show();
```

I use Jupyter Notebook.
I want to graph taylor series of exp(x).
I just success to graph exp(x) but failed taylor seires of exp(x).
Sympy library has taylor series fuction so I tried it but I don't understand what's the problem.
below is the error message and graph.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sy.exp(x).series(x)` creates a sympy expression, not a function

you might want to convert it to a function

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

x = sy.Symbol('x')
exp_expr = sy.exp(x).series(x).removeO()
exp_func = lambdify(x, exp_expr)
```

and plot it out

```
x_points = np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 100)
plt.plot(x_points, [exp_func(i) for i in x_points])
```

Comment: I typed expr = sy.exp(x).series(x).remove() but error message says  'Add' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: it is `removeO()` for removing the big O notation